# Does longer straw has its advantage with suction force than shorter straw?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, vacuum

After the pandemic, I've gotten chances to use various types of hand sanitizers with different design of bottles. Among them, I've found that the bottles with longer straws (I couldn't find the exact vocabulary for this, but I hope you could get what I mean since we all use hand sanitizers these days) show some better performance with its suction force.

How do I know that?

When we use 500ml size of hand sanitizers, we often observe that the gels left near the bottom of the bottle are hard to be inhaled into the straw to be arrived to our hands.

However when I use bottles with longer straws, I've found that I could use almost every of the gels left near the bottom of the bottle.

I assume this shouldn't be a coincidence. Therefore,

> **Assumption**: Among two straws of different lengths, a longer straw has advantage with suction force over the shorter straw, when all else conditions being equal.

Could anyone give some hint or advice that accounts for my assumption? Thanks.

Comment: FYI: A "straw" that draws liquid up from the bottom of a bottle or a tank or other vessel is properly known as a [_dip tube_](https://www.pexco.com/custom-plastic-extrusion/specialty/dip-tubes/).

Comment: @SolomonSlow: Wow, thanks a lot. I've really wondered what the word would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think so. For the scenario you describe of getting the last bits out of the bottle, and all other conditions being equal, the longer straw should have to battle a higher hydrostatic pressure difference and thus be at a disadvantage. Viscous forces adding up over a greater length of straw won't help either...

But then there are so many different variables at play: Straw length, diameter, power of the pump, fluid viscosity, bottle geometrym (specifically the bottom and how the straw lands on it).

What might be the case - and this is a wild guess, I think - that the longer straw has a more powerful pump fitted and when you get to the rest of the bottle and there is already some air in the straw (such that hydrostatic pressure will play no or a lesser role), then the higher power of the pump might empty the rest of the bottle more easily. Not at all sure, if that's the case.

Comment: Pump should be the vocabulary I've been finding. While considering more about the problem under your opinion, I may see if there are some other opinions. Thank you for your answer.